# Removing multiple bits of text in paranthesis from a text file using python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm extremely new to coding and python so bear with me.

I want to remove all text that is in parenthesis from a text file. There are multiple sets of parenthesis with varying lengths of characters inside. From another similar post on here, I found

```
re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)', '', "sample.txt")
```

which is supposed to remove characters between () but does absolutely nothing. It runs but I get no error code.

I've also tried

```
intext = 'C:\\Users\\S--\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\sample.txt'
outtext = 'C:\\Users\\S--\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\EDITEDsample.txt'

with open("sample.txt", 'r') as f, open(outtext, 'w') as fo:
    for line in f:
        fo.write(line.replace('\(.*?\)', '').replace('(', " ").replace(')', " "))
```

which successfully removes the parenthesis but nothing inbetween them.

How do I get the characters between the parenthesis out?

EDIT: I was asked for a sample of sample.txt, these are it's contents:

> Example sentence (first), end of sentence. Example Line (second), end
> of sentence (end).

Comment: Could you please give us a sample text in sample.txt?

Comment: `string.replace` does not handle regex, use `re.sub`

Answer (score -1):

As you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), the function `sub` does not receive a filename as parameter, but actually it receives the text on which to work.

```
>>> re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)', '', "123(456)789")
'123789'
```

As for your second attempt, notice that [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) does not take in REGEX expressions, only literal strings.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding, re.sub replaces characters in a string that I have to provide, but how can it be used to replace characters in a text file?